# Для чего во flask debugger pin?

Tags: python, flask

Если запустить код с Flask с включённым дебагом, то появляется такое сообщение:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with inotify reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: xxx-xxx-xxx
```

Где *xxx-xxx-xxx* это пин. 
Для чего нужен этот пин ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот для этого:

[image]

Эта страница с сообщением об ошибке позволяет открыть интерактивную консоль Python ровно в том месте, где возникла ошибка, и тут любому должно быть очевидно, что это жуть как небезопасно. Поэтому она защищена пином, который по идее знает только разработчик, а не какой-нибудь хакер из интернета, пришедший на открытый порт (хотя открытый наружу порт сам по себе ошибка):

[image]

[image]